# Brakes going to floor

Tags: chevrolet, brakes, silverado

Chevy silverado c1500 1991My brake pedal is going to the floor effortlessly. I've bled it multiple times, the brake lights are on bright red, and I've replaced the master cylinder and the brake booster . I'm thinking there is a leak in the lines. I'm not sure though as I checked and didn't see any. The master cylinder is brand new from autozone, replaced HR about a month ago. Brake fluid is new. And clean. The brakes work when I pump them though. Just hit me back with a idea please. A

Comment: Did properly bench bleed the master cylinder prior to installation. Do you have ABS?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If there's a leak in the lines, then a) the fluid level in the reservoir will go down, and b) there'd be a puddle of brake fluid on the ground.